# Compare Second Derivatives of Two Functions

Tags: calculus

If I have two functions $f$ and $g$ on the same domain $D$, and their first derivatives are both $\geq 0$. If the second derivative of $f$ is $\geq$ the second derivative of $g$, can we conclude that $f\geq g$ on $D$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that assumption can be false. Take $2x^2$ and $x^2 +1000$ where x is equal  to $2$.
If you are talking about multivariable functions, take $10x^3y^3$ and $x^2y^2 +10000$. The derivates just show the rate of change and say nothing about the value of a function, a negative valued function can have a positive derivates and vice versa. You can think about displacement, velocity and acceleration if you are familiar with physics.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $f(x) = 2x^2$ and $g(x)= x^2 + 10$ Then $f''(x) = 4 > g''(x)=2$ but $f(2) = 8$ and $g(2) = 14$ so $g(2) >f(2)$.